# How to decode the contents of a block using `tezos-codec`

Tags: block, encoding

How do I extract the operations from a block using `tezos-codec`?

I can decode the block header as follows below, but I'm interested in seeing the contents of the block.

```
export BLOCK="019caecab9000753d3029bc7d9a36b60cce68ade985a0a16929587166e0d3de61efff2fa31b7116bf670000000005ee3c23b04519d71c4e54089c56773c44979b3ba3d61078ade40332ad81577ae074f653e0e0000001100000001010000000800000000000753d2da051ba81185783e4cbc633cf2ba809139ef07c3e5f6c5867f930e7667b224430000cde7fbbb948e030000"
tezos-codec decode \
    006-PsCARTHA.block_header.unsigned \
    from \
  ${BLOCK:10}
```

Comment: Please do not ask almost the same question 2x. I closed the previous one

Comment: Both questions are different. On SE we should ask one specific question per-post. One is about endorsements, the other is about block contents.

Comment: Endorsements are part of the block

Comment: I argue that they are still distinct questions. An answer to one will not answer the other. They both serve value to the ecosystem as specific questions.